# Changing Haproxy configuration on openshift

Tags: openshift, haproxy

I have a scalable Python 2.7 app on OpenShift and I'm getting this 503 error.
I checked some answers that might work but they say to rhc into the app and change the Haproxy configurations, but I don't have a clue on how to do it.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2):

1) Install `rhc`: https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-client-tools.html and read https://blog.openshift.com/how-haproxy-scales-openshift-apps/

2) Run `$ rhc setup`  for the initial configuration of the tool and check https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-log-files.html#accessing-logs-via-ssh for viewing haproxy logs

3) Run `rhc ssh --app yourapp`, once inside, `cd haproxy/conf` and change your `haproxy.cfg` appropriately

Comment: I could find the haproxy.cfg file but I don't know how to open it to edit and save. Can you tell me how to do it? I know very little about rhc commands.

Comment: @BrunoLucena  You need to open it with some text editor such as vim or nano (`$ nano haproxy.cfg`)

Answer (score 0):

I edited `haproxy.cfg`:

```
option httpchk OPTIONS * HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:\ {{ my app link }}
```

It’s working now.